# How do I setup MOQ without Repository? System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, moq

This is the constructor of my test class

```
public IngestServiceTest()
{
    IConfiguration configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile("appsettings.test.json").Build();
    _logger = LoggerFactory.Create(builder => builder.AddConsole()).CreateLogger<object>();
    
    var fileProcessLogDbSetMock = new Mock<DbSet<FileProcessLog>>();
    mockDowJonesContext.Setup(s => s.FileProcessLogs).Returns(fileProcessLogDbSetMock.Object);
    ingestService = new IngestService(mockDowJonesContext.Object, configuration, _logger);
}
```

But it hits `System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'` at `mockDowJonesContext.Setup(s => s.FileProcessLogs).Returns(fileProcessLogDbSetMock.Object);`

I see many tutorial but it is with Repository but mine is without Repository.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mockDowJonesContext needs to be initialized